# Try to modify script ccxt python binance spot dca bot

Tags: python, binance, ccxt

Hello I need help for the modification of a python script of dca bot on binance, I want to modify the original script which trades on binance future, I modified the exchange part but I meet this problem when I try running the script in visual studio :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\TEHH\Desktop\Binance-Futures-DCA-4Bot-main\Binance-Futures-DCA-Bot-main\strategy copy 2.py", line 41, in 
positions = balance['info']['positions']

can you help me to modify the code to be able to use it on binance spot please,

> github ccxt : https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt.git

Code :

```
import config
import pandas as pd
import ccxt
import winsound
duration = 1000  # milliseconds
freq = 440  # Hz

# SETTİNGS
symbolName = input("Symbol (BTC, ETH, LTC...): ").upper()
baseOrderSize = float(input("Base Order Size: "))
safetyOrderSize = float(input("Safety Order Size: "))
maxSafetyTradesCount = float(input("Max Safety Trades Count: "))
priceDeviation = float(input("Price Deviation %: "))
safetyOrderStepScale = float(input("Safety Order Step Scale: "))
safetyOrderVolumeScale = float(input("Safety Order Volume Scale: "))
takeProfit = float(input("Take Profit %: "))
stopLoss = float(input("Stop Loss %: "))
positionSide = float(input("Position Side = Only Long(1) - Only Short(2) - Long and Short(3): "))

#ATTRIBUTES
first = True
tradeCount = 1
symbol = symbolName+"/BTC"
mainSafetyOrderSize = safetyOrderSize
mainPriceDeviation = priceDeviation

# API CONNECT
exchange = ccxt.binance({
"apiKey": config.apiKey,
"secret": config.secretKey,
'enableRateLimit': True
})

while True:
    try:
        
        balance = exchange.fetch_balance()
        free_balance = exchange.fetch_free_balance()
        positions = balance['info']['positions']
        newSymbol = symbolName+"BTC"
        current_positions = [position for position in positions if float(position['positionAmt']) != 0 and position['symbol'] == newSymbol]
        position_info = pd.DataFrame(current_positions, columns=["symbol", "entryPrice", "unrealizedProfit", "isolatedWallet", "positionAmt", "positionSide"])
        
        # in position?
        if not position_info.empty and position_info["positionAmt"][len(position_info.index) - 1] != 0:
            inPosition = True
        else: 
            inPosition = False
            longPosition = False
            shortPosition = False
            
        # in long position?
        if not position_info.empty and float(position_info["positionAmt"][len(position_info.index) - 1]) > 0:
            longPosition = True
            shortPosition = False
        # in short position?
        if not position_info.empty and float(position_info["positionAmt"][len(position_info.index) - 1]) < 0:
            shortPosition = True
            longPosition = False
        
        
        # LOAD BARS
        bars = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(symbol, timeframe="1m", since = None, limit = 1)
        df = pd.DataFrame(bars, columns=["timestamp", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume"])
        
        # Starting price
        if first:
            firstPrice = float(df["close"][len(df.index) - 1])
            first = False

        currentPrice = float(df["close"][len(df.index) - 1])
        
        # LONG ENTER
        def longEnter(alinacak_miktar):
            order = exchange.create_market_buy_order(symbol, alinacak_miktar)
            winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
            
        # LONG EXIT
        def longExit():
            order = exchange.create_market_sell_order(symbol, float(position_info["positionAmt"][len(position_info.index) - 1]), {"reduceOnly": True})
            winsound.Beep(freq, duration)

        # SHORT ENTER
        def shortEnter(alincak_miktar):
            order = exchange.create_market_sell_order(symbol, alincak_miktar)
            winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
            
        # SHORT EXIT
        def shortExit():
            order = exchange.create_market_buy_order(symbol, (float(position_info["positionAmt"][len(position_info.index) - 1]) * -1), {"reduceOnly": True})
            winsound.Beep(freq, duration)

        if inPosition == False:
            priceDeviation = mainPriceDeviation
            safetyOrderSize = mainSafetyOrderSize
        
        # LONG ENTER
        if firstPrice - (firstPrice/100) * priceDeviation >= currentPrice and shortPosition == False and maxSafetyTradesCount>tradeCount and float(free_balance["BTC"]) >= baseOrderSize and (positionSide == 1 or positionSide == 3):
            if tradeCount == 0:
                alinacak_miktar = (baseOrderSize * 1 ) / float(df["close"][len(df.index) - 1])
            if tradeCount > 0:
                alinacak_miktar = (safetyOrderSize * 1 ) / float(df["close"][len(df.index) - 1])
                safetyOrderSize = safetyOrderSize*safetyOrderVolumeScale

            priceDeviation = priceDeviation * safetyOrderStepScale
            longEnter(alinacak_miktar)
            print("LONG ENTER")
            first = True
            tradeCount = tradeCount + 1
        
        # SHORT ENTER
        if ((firstPrice / 100) * priceDeviation) + firstPrice <= currentPrice and longPosition == False and maxSafetyTradesCount>tradeCount and float(free_balance["BTC"]) >= baseOrderSize and (positionSide == 2 or positionSide == 3): 
            if tradeCount == 0:
                alinacak_miktar = (baseOrderSize * 1 ) / float(df["close"][len(df.index) - 1])
            if tradeCount > 0:
                alinacak_miktar = (safetyOrderSize * 1 ) / float(df["close"][len(df.index) - 1])
                safetyOrderSize = safetyOrderSize*safetyOrderVolumeScale

            priceDeviation = priceDeviation * safetyOrderStepScale
            shortEnter(alinacak_miktar)
            print("SHORT ENTER")
            first = True
            tradeCount = tradeCount + 1
            
            
        # LONG TAKE PROFIT
        if longPosition and ((float(position_info["entryPrice"][len(position_info.index) - 1])/100)*takeProfit)+float(position_info["entryPrice"][len(position_info.index) - 1]) < currentPrice and (positionSide == 1 or positionSide == 3):
            print("TAKE PROFIT")
            longExit()
            first = True
            tradeCount = 0
            
        # SHORT TAKE PROFIT
        if shortPosition and float(position_info["entryPrice"][len(position_info.index) - 1]) - (float(position_info["entryPrice"][len(position_info.index) - 1])/100) * takeProfit >= currentPrice and (positionSide == 2 or positionSide == 3):
            print("TAKE PROFIT")
            shortExit()
            first = True
            tradeCount = 0
            
        # LONG STOP LOSS
        if longPosition and (float(free_balance["BTC"]) <= baseOrderSize or maxSafetyTradesCount<=tradeCount) and firstPrice - (firstPrice/100) * stopLoss >= currentPrice and (positionSide == 1 or positionSide == 3):
            print("STOP LOSS")
            longExit()
            first = True
            tradeCount = 0
        
        # SHORT STOP LOSS
        if shortPosition and (float(free_balance["BTC"]) <= baseOrderSize or maxSafetyTradesCount<=tradeCount) and ((firstPrice / 100) * stopLoss) + firstPrice <= currentPrice and (positionSide == 2 or positionSide == 3):
            print("STOP LOSS")
            shortExit()
            first = True
            tradeCount = 0
            
            
        if longPosition:
            print("In Long Position")
        if shortPosition:
            print("In Short Position")
        if inPosition:
            print("Trade Count: ", tradeCount, " Avarege Price: ", float(position_info["entryPrice"][len(position_info.index) - 1]), " Free btc ", round(float(free_balance["BTC"]),2), " Total Money: ", round(float(balance['total']["BTC"]),2))
        if inPosition == False: 
            print("Starting Price: ", firstPrice, " Current Price: ", currentPrice, " Total Money: ", round(float(balance['total']["BTC"]),2))
        print("=======================================================================================================================================")

    except ccxt.BaseError as Error:
        print ("[ERROR] ", Error )
        continue
```

Comment: When asking something, try explain what you want to achieve as specific as possible. From your link I see DCA (DCA=Dollar Cost Average) and I guess most people are unfamiliar with cryptocurrencies. Saying "I want this scrpt to work in Lamborgini as it works now in Futures Car" does not help. A.k.a. your script works in Futures section of crypto Binance exchange and you would like to be fixed to work also in the Spot section of crypto Binance exchange. I assume this is what you want.

Comment: Ccxt library has methods that work in both "Futures" and "Spot". You need to understand each sections' functionalities. I am unfamiliar with Futures. I know Spot section and Margin Trading. I can provide you with one example in order make myself more clear: Margin Trading has two (sub)sections and one of them (Isolated) has the available balances exclusivelly allocated to this activity, while the other (sub)section (i.e. Cross) use all balances (including Spot balances) for trading. Fixing a functionality from Futures to work also in Spot could be a false problem (or it may work-I don't know).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The picture above is the outcome of running the method .fetch_balance() applicable to Binance crypto exchange (wrapped by ccxt library). It is in JSON format and I believe that instead of

```
positions = balance['info']['positions']
```

you should try

```
positions = balance['info']['balances']
```

I cannot guarantee if this will pass that the rest of code will work as Futures is different that Spot and I am unfamiliar with Futures.